# Magento 2 custom option not showing created programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, custom-options

I have created a script that will generate the custom option in the product. It's working properly and generate the custom option programmatically.

On the frontend, it's not showing the custom option when we open the product in admin shows the custom option.  If I save that product again from admin than custom option will show up on the frontend.

When I run this script from Magento 2 root it generates the option in the product but I need to save that product from admin then after options show up on the frontend.

What could be the issue? Any help would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
  $custom_options ="4:fixed:0:0;4.5:fixed:0:1;5:fixed:0:2;";



  $Products =  $productCollection->create()
             ->addAttributeToSelect(['id','sku'])
            ->addOrder('entity_id','desc')->load();


    foreach ($Products as $Product) { 
          insertProductCustomOptions($Product->getId(), $custom_options, $custom_option_label, $Product->getSku(), 1);
       }


  function insertProductCustomOptions($product_id, $option_data, $option_title, $sku, $is_require) {    
//    

try{

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
// check if product option is already there
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
// Set option array
$allOptionsArray = $customOptions->getData();

$flag = 0;

// Collect all options values
foreach ($allOptionsArray as $allOpKey => $allOpVal) {



    if($allOpVal['title'] == $option_title) {

        $flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}       
if ($flag == 1) {

    $optionValues = explode(';', $option_data);
    $options_arr = array();
    $cos = $co = array();
    foreach ($optionValues as $optionValue) {
        $optionValueData = explode(':', $optionValue);
        if (count($optionValueData) >= 3) {

            $optionValueDataLabel = $optionValueData[0];
            $optionValueDataPriceType = $optionValueData[1];
            $optionValueDataPrice = $optionValueData[2];
            $optionValueDataSortOrder = 1;
            if (count($optionValueData) >= 4) {


                $optionValueDataSortOrder = $optionValueData[3];
            }       
            $option_sku = $sku . ' ' . $optionValueDataLabel;       
            $options_arr[$option_sku] = array('title' => $optionValueDataLabel, 'price' => $optionValueDataPrice, 'price_type' => $optionValueDataPriceType, 'sku' => $sku . ' ' . $optionValueDataLabel, 'sort_order' => $optionValueDataSortOrder, 'exist_flag' => 0, );      
        }       
    }
    // Get all options
    foreach ($customOptions as $o) {

        if ($o -> getTitle() == $option_title) {
            $values = $o -> getValuesCollection();  
            foreach ($values as $k => $v) {

                $option_sku_existing = $v -> getSku();
                if (array_key_exists($option_sku_existing, $options_arr)) {

                    $v -> setTitle($options_arr[$option_sku_existing]['title']) -> setSku($option_sku_existing) -> setPriceType($options_arr[$option_sku_existing]['price_type']) -> setSortOrder($options_arr[$option_sku_existing]['sort_order']) -> setPrice(floatval($options_arr[$option_sku_existing]['price']));     
                    // set exist flasg to 1
                    $options_arr[$option_sku_existing]['exist_flag'] = 1;       
                    $v -> setOption($o) -> save();      
                    $cos[] = $v -> toArray($co);
                } else {
                    // remove all other skus which are not present
                    $v -> delete();     
                }       
            }
            // Option array
            foreach ($options_arr as $osku => $oval) {
                if ($oval['exist_flag'] == 0) {

                    // add those values which are not there already
                    $value = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value");
                    $value -> setOption($o) -> setTitle($oval['title']) -> setSku($oval['sku']) -> setPriceType($oval['price_type']) -> setSortOrder($oval['sort_order']) -> setPrice(floatval($oval['price'])) -> setOptionId($o -> getId());

                    $value -> save();
                    $cos[] = $value -> toArray($co);

                }

            }   
            $o -> setData("values", $cos) -> save();                        
        }       
    }

} else {
    // add all new attributes       
    $options_arr[$sku] = array('title' => $option_title, 'type' => 'drop_down', 'is_require' => $is_require, 'sort_order' => 0, 'values' => array());       
    $optionValues = explode(';', $option_data);
    foreach ($optionValues as $optionValue) {
        $optionValueData = explode(':', $optionValue);
        if (count($optionValueData) >= 3) {
            $optionValueDataLabel = $optionValueData[0];
            $optionValueDataPriceType = $optionValueData[1];
            $optionValueDataPrice = $optionValueData[2];
            $optionValueDataSortOrder = 0;
            if (count($optionValueData) >= 4) {
                $optionValueDataSortOrder = $optionValueData[3];
            }       
            $options_arr[$sku]['values'][] = array('title' => $optionValueDataLabel, 'price' => $optionValueDataPrice, 'price_type' => $optionValueDataPriceType, 'sku' => $sku . ' ' . $optionValueDataLabel, 'sort_order' => $optionValueDataSortOrder);      
        }
    }
    $product -> setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
            $product -> setHasOptions(1);
    foreach ($options_arr as $sku => $customOptions) {

        $option = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
                ->setProductId($product_id)
                ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                ->addData($customOptions);
        $option->save();
        $product->addOption($option);
    }
     unset($options_arr);
     unset($optionValues);

  }

   }
 catch (Exception $e)
 {
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: hi, any luck ? i have same issue

Comment: Hi No help from others. I have  created one solution for this.  i have created one module and using that getting customer details from seesion and using require js have appended it there.  It's working fine.

Comment: Do you want that extension?

Comment: Ok sure. I'll add it here.